# How to remove parent element in filter

Tags: angular, filter

I have this model:

```
export class food_items {
    constructor(
        public itemname: string,
    )   {}
}
export class Foods {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public items: food_items[]
    )   {}
}
```

and data:

```
foods: Foods [];

getTable(){ 
    this.foods=[
      {
       "name": "fruits"
       "items":[
            {"itemname": "apple"},
            {"itemname": "banana"},
            {"itemname": "orange"}
          ]},
     {  
      "name": "vegetables"
      "items": [
           {"itemname": "carrot"},
           {"itemname": "cucumber"}, 
           {"itemname": "tomato"},   
         ]}
}
```

and use pipe to filter them by itemname like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let food of foods>
    {{food.name}}
<div *ngFor="let item of items | myfilter: filterargs">
    {{item.itemname}}
```

pipe:

```
export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {
    temp = [];
    transform (value, queryString) {
        this.temp.length = 0;
        let arr=value.filter((item)=> new 
           RegExp(queryString.toLowerCase()).test(item.itemname.toLowerCase()));
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
           this.temp.push(arr[i]);
        }
    return this.temp;
}
```

}

if a put carrot in filterargs i will have this:

```
fruits
vegetables
    carrot
```

my question is how can I remove fruits element or other empty parent element whitch does not contain filterargs? Thanks.

Comment: So, do you expect us to rewrite the whole pipe for you, or will you post its code, so we can help improving it? How about posting valid JSON, too, so that we can know the actual structure of what the pipe is supposed to filter?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Ah. So your pipe doesn't filter foods. It only filters the food items. Either make it filter foods (keeping only the foods which have an item obeying the filter, and creating a partial copy of each food containing only the matching items), or don't use a pipe, and do that in your controller code (preferred solution: see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-).

Comment: And can you show me how should I change the pipe to do this?

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this?